# Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 70

Tags: ios, jpeg

How to solve this bug:
When i trying to load a JPG file (png, bmp, .. all is fine), then i see in console this error

```
Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 70
```

and my JPG file is not loading.

I am using libjpeg 7.0 version and error come in image decode function at code line:

```
jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
```

**But**, in example project is all fine. So interesting

Comment: Please compile your app, go to the app bundle and then display all linked libraries using `$ otool -L app-binary` and then add the results to your question.

Comment: thanks, but **otool** - command not found

Comment: Have you installed the Xcode Command Line tools?

Comment: It seems, no. I will try install him and post a result

Comment: @trojanfoe I runned, but i see this error: **otool: can't open file: 1.app (Invalid argument)**

Comment: You have you run it on the executable, not the app bundle.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for your help, but i solved this with way: Recreating a XCode project file =)

Answer (score -1):

Solved. I removed a project file and was create a new XCode project file and add him a resources and sources.

Now, all works at fine.

Comment: Can you explain this more, I also have this problem where mine is "wrong jpeg library version: library is 80,caller expects 62" . I didn't understand your solution. Thanks